# Factory Method Using Is/As Operator

Tags: c#, factory

I have factory that looks something like the following snippet. Foo is a wrapper class for Bar and in most cases (but not all), there is a 1:1 mapping. As a rule, Bar cannot know anything about Foo, yet Foo takes an instance of Bar. Is there a better/cleaner approach to doing this?

```
public Foo Make( Bar obj )
{
    if( obj is Bar1 )
        return new Foo1( obj as Bar1 );
    if( obj is Bar2 )
        return new Foo2( obj as Bar2 );
    if( obj is Bar3 )
        return new Foo3( obj as Bar3 );
    if( obj is Bar4 )
        return new Foo3( obj as Bar4 ); // same wrapper as Bar3
    throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

At first glance, this question might look like a duplicate (maybe it is), but I haven't seen one exactly like it. Here is one that is close, but not quite:

[Factory based on Typeof or is a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242097/factory-based-on-typeof-or-is-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you actually want to achieve. I would probably try to make it more generic.

You could use attributes on Foo, which Bar it supports, then you create a list in a initializing phase. We are doing quite a lot of stuff like this, it make adding and connecting new classes very easy.

```
private Dictionary<Type, Type> fooOfBar = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();
public initialize()
{
  // you could scan all types in the assembly of a certain base class
  // (fooType) and read the attribute

  fooOfBar.Add(attribute.BarType, fooType);
}

public Foo Make( Bar obj )
{
  return (Foo)Activator.CreateInstance(fooOfBar(obj.GetType()), obj);
}
```

Comment: I suggested something similar, but without the reflection.  The value of the dictionary could be a delegate instead of a raw type.

Comment: I've added a code sample to make that more clear.  While I haven't benchmarked it, I strongly suspect that the delegate approach will be faster than `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Comment: I just tried this approach and I like it very much. It is very clean and easily (trivially) maintained. Peak performance for this particular factory is not a necessity nor a requirement, otherwise, I would probably go with the response from @Steven, which I initially did.

Comment: @Swim: You don't have to decide.  If you use a delegate, you can either wire in the constructor explicitly or create it through Activator.

Answer (score 3):

If these are reference types, then calling `as` after `is` is an unnecessary expense.  The usual idiom is to cast with `as` and check for null.

Taking a step back from micro-optimization, it looks like you could use some of the techniques in the article you linked to.  In specific, you could create a dictionary keyed on the type, with the value being a delegate that constructs an instance.  The delegate would take a (child of) Bar and return a (child of) Foo.  Ideally, each child of Foo would register itself to the dictionary, which could be static within Foo itself.

Here's some sample code:

```
// Foo creator delegate.
public delegate Foo CreateFoo(Bar bar);

// Lookup of creators, for each type of Bar.
public static Dictionary<Type, CreateFoo> Factory = new Dictionary<Type, CreateFoo>();

// Registration.
Factory.Add(typeof(Bar1), (b => new Foo1(b)));

// Factory method.
static Foo Create(Bar bar)
{
    CreateFoo cf;
    if (!Factory.TryGetValue(bar.GetType(), out cf))
        return null;

    return cf(bar);
}
```

Comment: Right. I am aware that "is" is just a wrapped up "as" but having a long list of: 
Bar1 bar1 = obj as Bar1; 
if (bar1 != null ) 
   return new Foo1( bar1 );
just seems immensely ugly to me. ;-)

Comment: I'll keep watching this, because I don't know a better way than what you're doing and it's how I would solve this problem...

Comment: Swim, if you don't need the flexibility, then having a simple, fast but ugly method isn't so terrible.  For flexibility, consider the dictionary technique.

Comment: Dear downvoter (presumably Stefan): It's fine for you to downvote, but I'd love it if you explained why.

Comment: Uhm, I didn't vote anything here and I never downvote without a comment. It's probably the same who downvoted me?

Comment: Back to the topic: The delegate is nice, independent of the optimization. It allows any constructor signature. But you need to register all the types. This gives a high coupling of the factory to these types. So it depends on the situation where it is used, if the delegates are more appropriate as the fully generic (reflection with "automatic type registering") way. At the end, it is not much of a difference. It's just an implementation detail.

Comment: @Stefan: My apologies for jumping to conclusions.

Comment: @Stefan: What I like about the Activator approach is that it lends itself well to specifying the type as a configurable string.  That's why I've used it for things like plug-ins and, more generally, inversion of control.  In those cases, the late-bound object implemented an interface.  In the OP, we have children of a base class, so they're already coupled pretty tightly.  Calling a static method in the base to register themselves doesn't seem like a lot of additional coupling.  (continued)

Comment: Having said that, it would certainly be possible to combine the approaches to have the best of both worlds.  In this case, it could use a dictionary, but if no delegate is found, it could fall back to Activator.  So, yes, in the end, it's just an implementation detail and not a huge one.

Answer (score 1):

In your question the mapping from one set of classes into another set of classes looks quite simple. However, often you want to call specific constructors and/or set properties on the output classes based on the input classes. Sometimes you can use a library like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).

However, in other cases you need to create specific factory methods for each conversion. In your case it would be factory methods to create `Foo1` from `Bar1`, `Foo2` from a `Bar2` etc.:

```
Foo1 CreateFoo1(Bar1 bar1) { ... }

Foo2 CreateFoo2(Bar2 bar2) { ... }
```

You can store all these factory methods as delegates in a dictionary and then use the input type to select the factory to create the output type.

```
var inputType = input.GetType();
var factory = factories[inputType];
var output = factory(input);
```

By using reflection you can build this dictionary and to avoid the extra cost of using reflection while calling the factory you can use expressions to compile small lambdas the will do the required casting and calling.

This functionality can be exposed through a base class that assumes that the input types and output types are in parallel class hierarchies. E.g., in your case all the `Foo#` classes might have `Foo` as a base class and all the `Bar#` classes might have `Bar` as a base close. However, if that is not the case then all classes have `object` as a base class so this approach will still work.

Your derived factory class will look something like this:

```
public class FooFactory : TypeBasedFactory<Bar, Foo>
{
    private Foo1 CreateFoo1(Bar1 bar1)
    {
        return new Foo1(bar1.Id, bar1.Name, ...);
    }

    private Foo2 CreateFoo2(Bar2 bar2)
    {
        return new Foo2(bar2.Description, ...);
    }
}
```

Notice how the factory methods are private. They are not intended to be called directly. Instead `TypeBasedFactory` declares a `CreateFrom` method that will invoke the correct factory:

```
var fooFactory = new TypeBasedFactory<Bar, Foo>();
var foo = fooFactory.CreateFrom(bar);
```

Here is the code for `TypeBasedFactory`:

```
public abstract class TypeBasedFactory<TInput, TOutput>
    where TInput : class where TOutput : class
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<TInput, TOutput>> factories;

    protected TypeBasedFactory()
    {
        factories = CreateFactories();
    }

    private Dictionary<Type, Func<TInput, TOutput>> CreateFactories()
    {
        return GetType()
            .GetMethods(
                BindingFlags.Public
                | BindingFlags.NonPublic
                | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(methodInfo =>
                !methodInfo.IsAbstract
                && methodInfo.GetParameters().Length == 1
                && typeof(TOutput).IsAssignableFrom(methodInfo.ReturnType))
            .Select(methodInfo => new
            {
                MethodInfo = methodInfo,
                methodInfo.GetParameters().First().ParameterType
            })
            .Where(factory =>
                typeof(TInput).IsAssignableFrom(factory.ParameterType)
                && !factory.ParameterType.IsAbstract)
            .ToDictionary(
                factory => factory.ParameterType,
                factory => CreateFactory(factory.MethodInfo, factory.ParameterType));
    }

    private Func<TInput, TOutput> CreateFactory(MethodInfo methodInfo, Type parameterType)
    {
        // Create this Func<TInput, TOutput>: (TInput input) => Method((Parameter) input)
        var inputExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TInput), "input");
        var castExpression = Expression.Convert(inputExpression, parameterType);
        var callExpression = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(this), methodInfo, castExpression);
        var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TInput, TOutput>>(callExpression, inputExpression);
        return lambdaExpression.Compile();
    }

    public TOutput CreateFrom(TInput input)
    {
        if (input == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
        var inputType = input.GetType();
        Func<TInput, TOutput> factory;
        if (!factories.TryGetValue(inputType, out factory))
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"No factory method defined for {inputType.FullName}.");
        return factory(input);
    }
}
```

The `CreateFactories` method uses reflection to look for both public and private methods that are able to create a `TOuput` (possibly a derived class) from a `TInput` (a non-abstract derived class).

The `CreateFactory` method creates a `Func<TInput, TOutput>` that does the required downcasting before invoking the factory method. Once the lambda has been compiled there is no reflection overhead in calling it.

Constructing a class derived from `TypeBasedFactory` will use reflection to build the dictionary of factories so you should avoid creating more than one instance (i.e., the factory should be a singleton).